# Concurrent Directory Move using C#

Tags: c#, file-io, parallel.foreach

I have got an interesting problem to solve related to the Directory Rename.

**Problem**:
A parent folder with plenty of subfolders which are named in a sequence
Example:

- data-500
- data-501
- data-502
- data-[n]

Each of the above folders contains subfolders and files within. The sequence of names are very important and they need to be sequential with that numbering as shown above.

There are cases when some of the folders get removed and my problem here is to RENAME the directories again so that all comes in a sequence

example if it starts from 500 to 600, and someone removed 550, now this logic should rename all in the order again from 500 to 599

As the parent folder contains huge number of subfolders, I need to apply the logic to run in PARALLEL

Basically, renaming the folders in **PARALLEL**

Tried: Directory.Move() which tries to move all the contents within the folders which is first waste of time and second it conflicts (throws exception) when running in Parallel as another thread might be trying to play on this same folder.

Tried: VisalBasic..Rename..() which also results the same as it is just a wrapper on top of Directory.Move()

Reducing the Parallel operation to 2 also does not solve this problem.

Only thing that works is Powershell RenameItem (running 2 thread at a time) which does perfectly but I need something in C# (not running powershell within C# please)

So in summary, need a direcoty rename (without moving may be) and run in parallel logic.

Is this possible?

Comment: As always a better design betters a better algorithm, thats to say, the requirement to have so many folders named sequentially and not a db that is linked to the contents seems the problem. However there are sometimes things out of our control. Firstly, renaming folders in parallel doesnt seem to be a hard thing to do, make a list of folders and work out the new namming, and use plinq or parallel.for. however on saying that i am not sure you will really get a huge performance gain.

Comment: I am not really sure why you cant enumerate directories, split parse number order, generate old and new name in annoymous type, run with TPL

Comment: A database is not an option for this as the folders are accessed in 100s of remote computer (Azure) which are deployed dynamically and processed from remote PowerShell.
I tried your approach with enumerate, split, generate old and new and with TPL, and there lies the problem which I have mentioned in the description where it does not work properly as the same folder may get accessed and results in an exception. I am looking for a better way or any new algorithm if someone has for this.